# How i can customize my checkbox with css and Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Im crating a form with many fields and a checkboxes, the problem is that im trying to customize the checkbox(unsuccessfully) according with the style of my form.

[image]

As you can see in the picture, the tick of the checkbox is black, and i need it green. How can I change the color? How can I change the size of checkbox?

This is my HTML:

```
        <div id="Cajamitad1">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="" >
                    <a class="FontStyle">Vegano</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
        <       div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">
                    <a class="FontStyle">Diabetico</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label><input type="checkbox" value="">
                    <a class="FontStyle">Celiaco</a>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

and this my CSS:

```
#ContForm{
    display: inline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.checkbox{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{
    margin-left: 5px;
}
#Cajamitad1{

    margin-top: 10px;
    width: 40%;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I know this is not possible.

Here is my reasoning: if you inspect the bootstrap checkbox then you see that the checkbox itself is drawn by an `<input type="checkbox">` and you have very limited control over that. Some browsers let you change the size of the checkbox but not all of them.

So the only thing you can do is to make your own checkbox, e.g. by using two images and some css.

Or often more mobile friendly are just two buttons side by side "yes" and "no". Then if you click one it becomes active, like some kind of toggle button.

Comment: instead of using images you can also use fontawesome and just change the font color

here is a nice example of how to customize checkboxes
http://codepen.io/jamesbarnett/pen/yILjk/

Comment: @BartKooi yes fontawesome truly deserves its name.

Comment: @maraca So, you know any tutorial about how create it?

Comment: @RandallDaniBarrientos No, I'm sorry, our customers don't like checkboxes ;-) I'm sure you'll find something with a search engine or here on SO.